# Magento-Check.php thinks I'm using a lower MySQL version than I am

Tags: mysql, magento

I've been having some site problems while developing and decided to run the magento-check.php file to see if everything is up to scratch. The results are.

```
Your server does not meet the following requirements in order to install Magento.
The following requirements failed, please contact your hosting provider in order to receive assistance with meeting the system requirements for Magento:

You need MySQL 4.1.20 (or greater)
The following requirements were successfully met:
You have PHP 5.2.0 (or greater)
Safe Mode is off
You have the curl extension
You have the dom extension
You have the gd extension
You have the hash extension
You have the iconv extension
You have the mcrypt extension
You have the pcre extension
You have the pdo extension
You have the pdo_mysql extension
You have the simplexml extension
```

The problem is that I am running MySql Server version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Also note that Magento is already installed on the server and operating.The problems I've been having are consistant 500 Internal Server Errors just on product pages. I don't think these problems are related but it's still odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a question in there, but if you're talking about the magento-check.php script distributed here

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento/
```

This gets the version of mysql with the following comment

```
preg_match('/[0-9]\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/', shell_exec('mysql -V'), $version);
```

and then compares using

```
if(version_compare($version[0], '4.1.20', '<')) {
```

In other words, the script runs the following shell command

```
$ mysql -V
```

and then looks for a X.X.X version number in the output.  For example, this

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for apple-darwin9.5.0 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

means the script thinks the version is `5.1.41`.

My guess is you're using a remove server. This means the script above checks the version of  the mysql cli client running **locally**.  It's also possible you don't have any mysql running locally, which means the script would try to parse the text

```
mysql: command not found
```

for a version number, and not find one.

As to your 500 Internal Server Errors, this means apache has an error, or PHP has an error.  Check their error logs respectively to see what the error is.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Magento is installed on a dedicated apache2 webserver and the database is on a separate dedicated database server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check Exact magento version support with php & mysql,i hope the below code may be help to check Exact Version PHP & MySQL

```
##Test What Exact Version PHP & MySQL
echo "<h2>Exact Version PHP & MySQL: </h2>";
printf("PHP version: %s\n", PHP_VERSION); 
$mysql = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'devonbd_com', 'XSZefjGW'); 
#$mysql = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
## Test the MySQL connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("</br> Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
## Print the MySQL server version 
printf("</br> MySQL server version: %s\n", mysqli_get_server_info($mysql)); 
##Close the MySQL connection 
mysqli_close($mysql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue. It turns out that the MySQL warning might be a false alarm; for me, changing the PHP Version (I am using MAMP) from 7 to 5.6 did the trick. Looking at some forums, lowering the PHP version from 5.3 to 5.2 also worked for some.